# .NET System.Xml.Xsl.XslLoadException 'version' is an invalid attribute for the 'xsl:stylesheet' element

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xslt

I've googled for this error and can't find anything.

```
System.Xml.Xsl.XslLoadException 'version' is an invalid attribute for the 'xsl:stylesheet' element.
```

It was raised in our live system - since Windows updates applied at the weekend (or at least it would appear).  I don't have further information from our support team.

#### Call Stack:

```
at System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform.LoadInternal(Object stylesheet, XsltSettings settings, XmlResolver stylesheetResolver)     
at Acme.EDF.Xslt.Compile() in S:\MySource\Business Tier\BaseClasses\Xslt.cs:line 193     
at Acme.EDF.TransformDocumentUsingXslt.Process(String document) in S:\MySource\Business Tier\StandardClasses\TransformDocumentUsingXSLT.cs:line 66     
at Acme.EDF.Engine.ImportDocument(String documentContents, Guid configurationGuid, String submissionDetails, Guid& contextGuid) in S:\MySource\Business Tier\BaseClasses\Engine.cs:line 148
```

#### Code

I cannot replicate the issue.  I've looked at the code and the following causes the problem - so the deployed code was moved to a simple console to try and replicate:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Xsl;

namespace XsltConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            var resourceName = "XsltConsoleApplication.stylesheet.xsl";

            string xml;

            using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                xml = reader.ReadToEnd();

                var b = XmlReader.Create(reader, null, "boom");
            }

            XmlDocument xsl = new XmlDocument();
            xsl.XmlResolver = null;
            xsl.LoadXml(xml);
            XsltUrlResolver resolver = new XsltUrlResolver();

            XslCompiledTransform compiled = new XslCompiledTransform();
            compiled.Load(xsl, null, resolver);

            Console.WriteLine("Done");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

#### XsltUrlResolver

I've also tried a custom XmlUrlResolver that our system does use.  However, there are a few statics in there which make it a nightmare to diagnose.  So I tried:

```
public class XsltUrlResolver : System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver
{
    public override object GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, string role, Type ofObjectToReturn)
    {
        object entity = null;
        entity = base.GetEntity(absoluteUri, role, ofObjectToReturn);

        throw new Exception("Boo hoo hoo");
    }
}
```

The exception doesn't get thrown in the console application - without further checking down the XslCompiledTransform call tree - I hopefully can rule this out from raising the exception.

#### XSL

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:pro="http://www.acme.com/xml/xml-ns" version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()[not(self::pro:Import)]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="pro:Import">
    <pro:Import xmlns:pro="http://www.acme.com/xml/xml-ns">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </pro:Import>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The problem lies in the XslCompiledTransform.  I have decompiled the Microsoft code but nothing stood out as yet.  I would assume the exception is thrown when the xslt is loaded in LoadInternal:

#### XslCompiledTransform.LoadInternal

```
private CompilerResults LoadInternal(object stylesheet, XsltSettings settings, XmlResolver stylesheetResolver)
{
    if (stylesheet == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("stylesheet");
    }
    if (settings == null)
    {
        settings = XsltSettings.Default;
    }
    this.CompileXsltToQil(stylesheet, settings, stylesheetResolver);
    CompilerError firstError = this.GetFirstError();
    if (firstError != null)
    {
        throw new XslLoadException(firstError);
    }
    if (!settings.CheckOnly)
    {
        this.CompileQilToMsil(settings);
    }
    return this.compilerResults;
}
```

I just want to replicate the issue - so I can throw the XslLoadException with the message about the version attribute causing a problem.

I have tried tweaking the xsl many ways but I cannot get this exception/message to be thrown.

**Update**

It looks like exceptions are collated when loaded.  I tracked down the error string resource through the code and it looks like the following classes throws the specific exception:

**Compiler**

```
internal string GetSingleAttribute(string attributeAtom)
{
    NavigatorInput input = this.Input;
    string localName = input.LocalName;
    string value = null;
    if (input.MoveToFirstAttribute())
    {
        do
        {
            string namespaceURI = input.NamespaceURI;
            string str = input.LocalName;
            if (!Keywords.Equals(namespaceURI, this.Atoms.Empty))
            {
                continue;
            }
            if (!Keywords.Equals(str, attributeAtom))
            {
                if (this.ForwardCompatibility)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                string[] strArrays = new string[] { str, localName };
                throw XsltException.Create("Xslt_InvalidAttribute", strArrays);
            }
            else
            {
                value = input.Value;
            }
        }
        while (input.MoveToNextAttribute());
        input.ToParent();
    }
    if (value == null)
    {
        throw XsltException.Create("Xslt_MissingAttribute", new string[] { attributeAtom });
    }
    return value;
}
```

**CompiledAction**

```
public void CompileAttributes(Compiler compiler)
{
    NavigatorInput input = compiler.Input;
    string localName = input.LocalName;
    if (input.MoveToFirstAttribute())
    {
        do
        {
            if (!Keywords.Equals(input.NamespaceURI, input.Atoms.Empty))
            {
                continue;
            }
            try
            {
                if (!this.CompileAttribute(compiler))
                {
                    string[] strArrays = new string[] { input.LocalName, localName };
                    throw XsltException.Create("Xslt_InvalidAttribute", strArrays);
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                if (!compiler.ForwardCompatibility)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
        while (input.MoveToNextAttribute());
        input.ToParent();
    }
}
```

**ContainerAction**

```
internal void CompileKey(Compiler compiler)
{
    NavigatorInput input = compiler.Input;
    string localName = input.LocalName;
    int num = -1;
    int num1 = -1;
    XmlQualifiedName xmlQualifiedName = null;
    if (input.MoveToFirstAttribute())
    {
        do
        {
            string namespaceURI = input.NamespaceURI;
            string str = input.LocalName;
            string value = input.Value;
            if (!Keywords.Equals(namespaceURI, input.Atoms.Empty))
            {
                continue;
            }
            if (Keywords.Equals(str, input.Atoms.Name))
            {
                xmlQualifiedName = compiler.CreateXPathQName(value);
            }
            else if (Keywords.Equals(str, input.Atoms.Match))
            {
                num = compiler.AddQuery(value, false, false, true);
            }
            else if (!Keywords.Equals(str, input.Atoms.Use))
            {
                if (compiler.ForwardCompatibility)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                string[] strArrays = new string[] { str, localName };
                throw XsltException.Create("Xslt_InvalidAttribute", strArrays);
            }
            else
            {
                num1 = compiler.AddQuery(value, false, false, false);
            }
        }
        while (input.MoveToNextAttribute());
        input.ToParent();
    }
    base.CheckRequiredAttribute(compiler, num != -1, "match");
    base.CheckRequiredAttribute(compiler, num1 != -1, "use");
    base.CheckRequiredAttribute(compiler, xmlQualifiedName != null, "name");
    compiler.InsertKey(xmlQualifiedName, num, num1);
}

internal void CompileNamespaceAlias(Compiler compiler)
{
    NavigatorInput input = compiler.Input;
    string localName = input.LocalName;
    string nsAlias = null;
    string str = null;
    string value = null;
    string value1 = null;
    if (input.MoveToFirstAttribute())
    {
        do
        {
            string namespaceURI = input.NamespaceURI;
            string localName1 = input.LocalName;
            if (!Keywords.Equals(namespaceURI, input.Atoms.Empty))
            {
                continue;
            }
            if (Keywords.Equals(localName1, input.Atoms.StylesheetPrefix))
            {
                value = input.Value;
                nsAlias = compiler.GetNsAlias(ref value);
            }
            else if (!Keywords.Equals(localName1, input.Atoms.ResultPrefix))
            {
                if (compiler.ForwardCompatibility)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                string[] strArrays = new string[] { localName1, localName };
                throw XsltException.Create("Xslt_InvalidAttribute", strArrays);
            }
            else
            {
                value1 = input.Value;
                str = compiler.GetNsAlias(ref value1);
            }
        }
        while (input.MoveToNextAttribute());
        input.ToParent();
    }
    base.CheckRequiredAttribute(compiler, nsAlias, "stylesheet-prefix");
    base.CheckRequiredAttribute(compiler, str, "result-prefix");
    base.CheckEmpty(compiler);
    compiler.AddNamespaceAlias(nsAlias, new NamespaceInfo(value1, str, compiler.Stylesheetid));
}

internal void CompileStylesheetAttributes(Compiler compiler)
{
    NavigatorInput input = compiler.Input;
    string localName = input.LocalName;
    string str = null;
    string value = null;
    if (input.MoveToFirstAttribute())
    {
        do
        {
            string namespaceURI = input.NamespaceURI;
            string localName1 = input.LocalName;
            if (!Keywords.Equals(namespaceURI, input.Atoms.Empty))
            {
                continue;
            }
            if (Keywords.Equals(localName1, input.Atoms.Version))
            {
                value = input.Value;
                if (1 > XmlConvert.ToXPathDouble(value))
                {
                    if (compiler.ForwardCompatibility)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    string[] strArrays = new string[] { "version", value };
                    throw XsltException.Create("Xslt_InvalidAttrValue", strArrays);
                }
                else
                {
                    compiler.ForwardCompatibility = value != "1.0";
                }
            }
            else if (Keywords.Equals(localName1, input.Atoms.ExtensionElementPrefixes))
            {
                compiler.InsertExtensionNamespace(input.Value);
            }
            else if (!Keywords.Equals(localName1, input.Atoms.ExcludeResultPrefixes))
            {
                if (Keywords.Equals(localName1, input.Atoms.Id))
                {
                    continue;
                }
                str = localName1;
            }
            else
            {
                compiler.InsertExcludedNamespace(input.Value);
            }
        }
        while (input.MoveToNextAttribute());
        input.ToParent();
    }
    if (value == null)
    {
        throw XsltException.Create("Xslt_MissingAttribute", new string[] { "version" });
    }
    if (str != null && !compiler.ForwardCompatibility)
    {
        string[] strArrays1 = new string[] { str, localName };
        throw XsltException.Create("Xslt_InvalidAttribute", strArrays1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible the URLs for the namespaces were off-line?

Comment: Possibly... But would this throw an exception about version?

Comment: The Net xml methods ignore the namespace if the URL is not reachable.  But if the namespace wen't offline after the namespace was open I'm not sure what would happen.

Comment: I've added where in the code the exception (message) is used in the update.  I really want to debug down to this level but I can't.  But given that call stack, its when the xslt is initially loaded - I am struggling to see why the code would throw it `if (!Keywords.Equals(str, attributeAtom))`

Comment: The call stack will not help because you already moved up the call stack when the exception occurred.  I usually start putting in break points to isolate where exception is occurring and/or stepping through code.  Sometimes I just put break points on all the exception handlers until I fiind the one that is capturing the exception.

Comment: There is only 3 places buried deep in the System.XML and System.Data.SqlXml DLLs where this type of exception is raised for the message (see update).  I finally got the source debug-able using Jetbrains dotPeek - but having gone through hundreds of classes and countless lines, it seems like an unforgiving task. Like you said, the call stack don't help hence decompiling Microsoft source code - and trying to debug it.

Comment: So put a break point on the throw statements and then step (F11) to find out which exception handler is capturing the exception.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot see a way to open the class files.  I've generated the PDBs but tried stepping into the code for 30 minutes was tedious.  I'm trying to replicate this in my environment, but those errors wont get hit - plus I cannot see (watch) the value of the variables.

Comment: Is the exception occurring in the class files?

Comment: Its raised from LoadInternal.  Given the message and no InnerException by the looks of it, it is hard to pin point.  I cannot replicate it.

Comment: Yes I know.  It is due to exception jumping to a exception handler that isn't around where the exception is occurring.  When the exception occurs it moves up the execution stack and finds any exception handler in the parent function.  So you have to find the exception handler that is capturing the event.  Then find the child function where the exception is occurring which may not be inside the try where the exception is captured.

Comment: Indeed - hence `XsltException.Create` is raising exception for "Xslt_InvalidAttribute" that I posted.  I can catch duplicate attributes (tweak xslt) easily by breaking on XsltException System exceptions.  But there is no variable values available to watch - it feels like the blind leading the blind.

Comment: Do you mean the "Bind (no L) is leading the Blind".  The only way in Net of finding XML issues is to get the xml string and put into an xml checker.  I usually check in VS by using menu : Project : Add New Item : Xml file (or xml schema).  Then paste xml into view.